# Angular 9 How to generate reactive form controls automatically from indexes extracted from an array of data?

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I am trying to create a reactive form from indexes extracted from an array of data.

Lets say I have the following array:

```
array = [
  { name: 'Ali', gender: 'Male' },
  { name: 'Sara', gender: 'Female' }
];
```

I extracted the index as following:

```
this.result = new Set(this.array.flatMap(e => Object.keys(e), []));
this.result = Array.from(this.result);
```

And the result:

```
console.log(this.result)
// ["name", "gender"]
```

Now I need to loop over `this.result` and create 2 `form control names` with `formControlName='name'` and for gender as well.

Once the loop is done and the form controls are created, I need to display it on screen. Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ap1zwp) about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simple create a formGroup base of the array values now `fieldFormItems` will be an array of formGroups

*component*

```js
  createForm() : void{
    this.fieldForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fieldFormItems: this.formBuilder.array(
        this.array.map(values =>{
          return this.formBuilder.group(values)
        })
      )
    })
  }
```

*template*

```html
<div [formGroup]="fieldForm">
    <div formArrayName="fieldFormItems">
      <div *ngFor="let fg of fieldForm.get('fieldFormItems').controls" [formGroup]="fg" >
          <input formControlName="name">
          <input formControlName="gender">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Updated** ✨

get the form controls dynamically ‍♂️

```
div [formGroup]="fieldForm">
    <div formArrayName="fieldFormItems">
        <div *ngFor="let fg of fieldForm.get('fieldFormItems').controls" [formGroup]="fg">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let fc of fg.controls | keyvalue">
                <input type="text" [formControl]="fc.value">
      </ng-container>
    </div>
    </div>
</div
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmyyjb)

Comment: Thanks. But `<input formControlName="name">` are displayed statically. This is a basic example, because depending on users action, the array indexes may vary each time. So if the `formControlName` of user1 is `name` and `gender`, another user may select different arrays.

Comment: we can loop throw the formGroup controls this disaply the controls 

Comment: It worked. Just one more thing, how to get a value of an input? There is an array inside a form group which is confusing me here.

Comment: @alim1990 this way you will get the value for the form array `fieldForm.get('fieldFormItems').value` check the demo

Comment: `<ng-container *ngFor="let fc of fg.controls | keyvalue">` is returning 8 rows for each form control becuase it already contain 8 arrays. Why is that happening? I only need the value of the formcontrol as formcontrol name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210576/discussion-between-malbarmavi-and-alim1990).