# Angular 9 How to return only one drop down list form control name for each index of an array?

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

Based on the [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925681/angular-9-how-to-generate-reactive-form-controls-automatically-from-indexes-extr?answertab=active#tab-top) about generating `formControlName` for each extracted index of an array, I did the following:

Suppose we have and array of indexes called `odkDataIndexes` having lets say the following:

```
odkDataIndexes = ['id', 'name'];
```

So I need to generate 2 form controls with each having the correspondent names:

```
createIndexesForm(extractedIndexesArray): void {
  this.indexesForm = this.fb.group({
    mappingFieldItems: this.fb.array(
      extractedIndexesArray.map(values => {
        return this.fb.group(values);
      })
    )
  });
}
```

And then on button click, I need to generate the form controls:

```
async generateMappingFields() {
  this.showFields = false;
    if (this.odkDataIndexes.length > 0) {
      this.createIndexesForm(this.odkDataIndexes);
    }
  this.showFields = true;
}
```

At the HTML side I have the following:

```
<div *ngIf="showFields">
        <mat-spinner *ngIf="!indexesForm" value="50" class="setSpinnerOnTop" diameter="75" [color]="medair-color"></mat-spinner>
        <div [formGroup]="indexesForm" *ngIf="indexesForm">
            <div formArrayName="mappingFieldItems">
                <div *ngFor="let fg of indexesForm.get('mappingFieldItems').controls" [formGroup]="fg">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let fc of fg.controls | keyvalue">
                        <!-- <input type="text" [formControl]="fc.value"> -->
                        <span></span>
                        <mat-form-field class="formFieldWidth" color="warn" appearance="fill">
                            <mat-label>{{fc.value | keyvalue}}</mat-label>
                            <mat-select [formControl]="fc.value">

                                <mat-option (click)="getName(fc.value, de.id, fg.controls)" *ngFor="let de of dataElementsDetails; let i = index;" [value]="de.id">
                                    {{de.code}}

                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now for each index inside the `odkDataIndexes`, instead of showing only one drop down list per index, it is showing 7 or 8 depending on selected data.

The `getName(fc.value, de.id, fg.controls)` is retuning the following on click:

[image]

And this image shows that for only one index, there is 16 drop down list, and the last consoled value of `fg.ccontrols` contains 18 arrays.

[image]

I did a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdh6fa) with only the code in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use reactive form array just a formGroup can work for you by generate formGroup base of `dataIndexes` value

*component*

```js
createIndexesForm(extractedIndexesArray: string[]): void {
    // ["id", "name"]   {id:null,name:null}
    const controls = extractedIndexesArray.reduce((g, k) => {
      g[k] = null;
      return g;
    }, {});

    this.indexesForm = this.fb.group({
      mappingFieldItems: this.fb.group(controls)
    });
  }
```

*template*

```html
<div [formGroup]="indexesForm" *ngIf="indexesForm">
    <div [formGroup]="indexesForm.get('mappingFieldItems')">
        <div *ngFor="let controlName of dataIndexes">
            <mat-form-field class="formFieldWidth" color="warn" appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>{{controlName}}</mat-label>
                <mat-select [formControlName]="controlName">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let de of dataElementsDetails; let i = index;" 
                        [value]="de">
                        {{de}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prfxlb)

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't understand that part `// ["id", "name"]   {id:null,name:null}`. Why are we adding null values to the indexes?

Comment: this just a value here you don't have a default values , this.fb.group required an object where the property ethier a default value or array or null and if you want you can pass a validators but if will apply to al controls  `g[k] = [null,Validators.required];`